# Отсутствие запятой перед «и» в четверостишии

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, и

*Давайте радоваться звездам,

Луне, **и** солнцу, **и** ветрам,

**И** винограда спелым гроздьям,

Веселым песням **и** цветам.*

Верно ли отсутствует запятая перед последним словом (*и цветам*) в данном четверостишии? Если да, то какое правило здесь действует?

Answer (score 1):

> **7.** Между всеми однородными членами предложения **запятая** ставится также в том случае, когда только часть их связана повторяющимися союзами, а остальные соединяются бессоюзной связью: *Он слеп, упрям, нетерпелив, **и** легкомыслен, **и** кичлив* (П.)...

Это правило объясняет постановку запятых перед первыми тремя союзами "и".

> 9. Если союз **и** соединяет однородные члены предложения попарно, то **запятая** ставится только между *парами*, а внутри них не ставится: *Лицо Николая **и** голос, тепло **и** свет в комнате успокаивали Власову* (М. Г.)...

Однородные дополнения ***песням** и **цветам*** соединены в пару, поэтому запятая перед "и" не ставится.
**Вывод**: пунктуация в стихотворении правильная.

Вот ещё интересные стихи, в которых можно проследить правила постановки запятых в конструкциях с союзом "и" (Д. Самойлов. Снегопад):

*Он тёк, как лёгкий ровный душ,

Без звука **и** без напряженья

**И** тысячам усталых душ

Дарил покой **и** утешенье,

Он тёк на головной платок,

**И** на ресницы, **и** на щёки.

И выбившийся завиток

Плыл, как цветок, в его потоке.*

[Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)